# splitting sqlite file into smaller files

Tags: android, sql, database, sqlite

Ive been trying to research this for the last two hours and am so lost. I have a sqlite3 file that is way to big for android 2.2 - so I made a work around that gathers a few split up files from the assets and rewrites them in a new database on the device. Since I'm a noob at sqlite I cant figure out how to make the sqlite db split into multiple files under 700kb. I've tried different sql IDE's but to no avail. Do I need to do some command line prompt action? arg please help

Comment: under 700KB? SQLite even on Android 2.2 supports far bigger db size, it must be at least 1GB

Comment: What exactly is the problem with the big DB?

Answer (score 0):

You can always store every table in other files